# header:location not working

Tags: php, http-headers

I am some reason having trouble with this, my header redirect does not seem to work.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
      header('Location:home.php');
      exit;
   }
?>

<html>
   <body>
      Login Successful
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you defined `myusername` as a constant, you need to put quotes around that.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with if condition. Check if it works!

Comment: Have you enabled `error_reporting` yet? And `session_is_registered` is deprecated. Else [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957)

Comment: That was a accident.... btw...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
header("Location: home.php"); // there is a space
```

Comment: Are you sure the condition is satisfied ? Try replacing your header by an echo "test"; to see if "test" is displayed...

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, try

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
```

instead of

```
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
```

Comment: No, never get rid of exit; after a header to another page !

Comment: Can you explain? I've never used exit; when redirecting and never had any problems.

Comment: It's a security check ! It is recommended to use exit after a header to be sure that the code after isn't executed. The header redirects the user's browser to the new page, but the script is still being executed in the server side :)

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. I indeed never tried to run any other code after header redirects, which is probably why I did not (have to) use exit;. Will edit my reply if that's still possible? (I'm rather new to Stackoverflow...) -- Edit: Saw that an edit had been suggested and approved it!

Comment: Thanks, just approved it. :)